# ASP.NET 4.0 Routing and Subfolders

Tags: asp.net, routes, url-routing, asp.net-4.0

I have a folder structure like this:

```
www.mysite.com/About/About.aspx
```

I have a link in a user control like this:

```
<a href="~/About/About" id="aboutLink" title="About" runat="server">About</a>
```

And in my RegisterRoutes() method, I have this:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("", "About/About/", "~/About/About.aspx");
```

It works but produces the following URL:

```
www.mysite.com/About/About
```

What I would like is this:

```
www.mysite.com/About
```

Is this possible with out-of-the-box 4.0 routing?

**UPDATE 2 - 05-14-2010:**
Apparently, I introduced an extra issue by naming the .aspx Web Form the same as the containing folder. Finally, this is what worked for me:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("", "About/", "~/AboutUs/About.aspx");

<asp:HyperLink ID="aboutLink" NavigateUrl="~/About" 
    Text="About" runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>
```

The links provided by Raj helped me find the answer :-)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not clear to me. 
Try this

```
routes.MapPageRoute("", "About/", "~/About/About.aspx");
```

Also, consider using RouteURl expressions.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd329551.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668176.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter is how the URL will look and accessing the virtual page will do the trick

```
// Global.asax
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // Code that runs on application startup
    System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("", "About", "~/About/About.aspx");
}


<a href="/About" id="aboutLink" title="About" runat="server">About</a>
```

Comment: I've edited the question and replaced "mysite" with "www.mysite.com"

Comment: Gives me a 403.14 - Forbidden

Comment: I noticed now thanks to @Fyodor. You were using relative path in a HTML control. You can't do that, you need a asp:Hyperlink, or just put the full path. I fixed it.

Comment: It should work with a HTML control because I have runat="server"? Still can't get it to work; will try the Hyperlink control just to see :-)

Comment: +1 because you were close! See my comment to Fyodor about the naming :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `a` tag links to `/About/About`, so, naturally, that's what you get. Did you try to make it point to `/About` instead? (and correspondingly change the route definition)

Or do I misunderstand the question?

Comment: I think I introduced an extra problem by naming the Web Form the same as the folder...