# routing in asp.net with html page

Tags: asp.net, routes, asp.net-routing

i have a about.html page in my application.

i want to give this page routing for that i use this code in global file

```
 RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("AboutUs", "aboutus", "~/about.html");
```

but it gives me error like

There is no build provider registered for the extension '.html'. You can register one in the  section in machine.config or web.config. Make sure is has a BuildProviderAppliesToAttribute attribute which includes the value 'Web' or 'All'.

can anyone help me to give routing to this html page in asp.net not in mvc

thanks in advance

Comment: i have mentioned clearly what i want. can you help me for html page in asp.net ? not in mvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace `.html` by `.aspx`:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("", "AboutUs/", "~/AboutUs.aspx");
```

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831292/asp-net-4-0-routing-and-subfolders) can give you more details.

Update:

If you want to remove the extension check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481632/remove-html-or-aspx-extension)

Comment: but i don't want to convert that page with .aspx , i want to use it as .html page only

Comment: Check at my update, you can just remove the extension of your files in IIS instead of adding a new route for each single page.